# Склонение названия города Килия

Tags: склонение

Добрый день! Наш город называется Килия. И знаю, что правильно пишется в Килии, а не в Килие. Подскажите, правильно ли это?

Answer (score 1):

Это Одесская область?

Тогда да, такое склонение фиксируется словарём.
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?ag=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F

В принципе это и общим правилам склонения существительных соответствует, но в отношении имен собственных, топонимов в частности, лучше проверять по словарю, бывают особые случаи.

Но у вас однозначно - ***"в Килии"***.

Насчет ответа Сержа. 
Соврешенно недостоверное утверждение.
Словарь фиксирует форму КилиЯ. И именно для этой формы правильным будет в КилиИ. Подвижность ударения тут никаким образом...

Comment: behemothus, хотелось бы объяснений. Серж ведь по сути прав. Бог с ним с Зализняком и с формулировками, но ведь выбор формы  "-ие"  "-ии" действительно регулируется местом ударения. Мария-Марии-...-о Марии, Зульфия-Зульфии-...-о Зульфие. (русского имени, простите не вспомнил, но это обрусевшее основательно). Так почему ж "в Килии"-то? Да еще якобы "по общим правилам"? Не перемудрили часом? А что до словаря, так там указан явно только родительный падеж. Можно ли из него получить предложный?

Comment: Мне встречалась в Интернете запись "википедия о Килии",  но мне она не кажется верной при начальной форме КилиЯ.  Практически во всех случаях окончание И  для сущ. 1-го и 2-го склонений (с основой на И) в Д. и П. падежах является безударным, а при ударном окончании меняется на Е (в частности, остриЁ - на остриЕ). Есть ли еще случаи ударного варианта иИ, кроме КилиЯ - о КилиИ?

Comment: В Академическом справочнике сказано:  Немногочисленные существительные на -ий, -ия с одно- сложной основой имеют в указанных падежах в безударном положении по общему правилу окончание -е. Перечень таких слов: змий — о зми́е, кий — о ки́е (вариант: о кие́), Кий (легендарный основатель Киева) — о Кие, чий (растение) — о чие, «Вий» — в «Bue», Пий — о Пие, при папе Пие; хрия (термин риторики) — по хрие, о хрие; Бия (река) — по Бие, на Бие; Ия, Лия, Вия (женские имена) — к Ие, о Лие, о Bue; Гия (мужское имя) — к Гue, о Гue.

Comment: Но речь идет об односложных сущ-х, к тому же у Розенталя в этом случае в предложным падеже стоит "и".  При папе Пии X, на бильярдном кии, сестрам Ии и Лии, по реке Вии, на лезвии.

Comment: @Morkovkin, насчет родительного. Там в словаре последовательно прописываются все формы слов, для которых ***-ие***. Можете  убедиться на своей любимой Зульфи***е***. Там же, где указан только родительный падеж, надо понимать, регулярные формы на ***-ии***. Или нет? Остальное - позже. Не все понял из вашей логики. Не думаю, что перемудрил. А Вы, вслед за Сержем, не перечитали Лопатина? У Орфографической Комиссии были предложения упорядочить написание этих форм, как раз в части предложного падежа. Но ведь эта реформа так и осталась на бумаге.

Comment: @Sibylla *Есть ли еще случаи ударного варианта иИ, кроме КилиЯ - о КилиИ?* - Ну да, а иначе на основании чего я бы утверждал нормативность такой формы? Или**я**, Эвли**я**... Я думаю, вообще все закрепленные традицией написания, избежавших влияния реформы 1954. Именно их написание и предлагала  упорядочить лопатинская Орфографическая Комиссия. Кстати, там были вполне дельные предложения. Но всё "в гудок ушло".

Comment: Подождите, Бегемотус. Вы предлагаете писать Килии (или Илии)  только в предложном или еще и в дательном, как для "Марии"? Если последнее (а оно вытекает из вашей трактовки обозначений в словарях), то я совсем не согласен. Боюсь, вы неверно поняли словарь.

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос № 271665

Как правильно: в Килии или в Килие?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка (Грамота.ру)**

Принципиальное значение здесь имеет место ударения в названии. Слова на **-ия, где -я безударное,** имеют в предложном падеже окончание -и (станция – на станции, армия – в армии, Россия – в России). А вот если -я ударное, в предложном падеже окончание -е: Зульфия (имя) – Зульфие.

«Грамматический словарь русского языка» А. А. Зализняка отмечает, что есть два варианта: **КилИя (официальный) и КилиЯ (общеупотребительный).** Так же будут различаться и варианты написания: **в Килии (официальный) и в Килие (общеупотребительный).**

Comment: Так как правильно: КилиЯ или другое ударение? Если КилиЯ, то должно быть в КилиЕ. Такому же правилу подчиняется существительное "на остриЕ", где пишется ударное окончание Е.

Comment: Написано же : оба варианта верны. Один общеупотребительный, другой официальный.

Comment: У слова "острие" один вариант - ударный."На остриЕ"

Comment: Два варианта - это КилиЯ и КИлия? Произношение с разным ударением?

Comment: Я исправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, теперь всё ясно.

Comment: Боже, справка даже не удосужилась посмотреть словарь, на её страницах размещенный. А вы сюда это тащите.

Comment: @Sibylla  *КилиЯ или другое ударение?*  - КилиЯ, конечно. Что у аборигенов, что в словаре. Про Зализняка - не знаю, Зализняку бы поверил, Сержу верить опасаюсь (как, впрочем, любой ссылке на "официальную" версию). Как мог "неофициальный" вариант закрепиться в официальном   словаре (Агеенко, Словарь собственных имён русского языка © Электронная версия, «ГРАМОТА.РУ», 2011. ) - это надо додуматься.

Comment: http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F - Словарь Зализняка. Нет там ничего насчет двух вариантов. А в оригинальной версии, судя по всему, и слова-то такого нет. http://starling.rinet.ru

Comment: *У слова "острие" один вариант - ударный."На остриЕ"* Слова острие в русском нет. Есть  слово "остриё". И "вариантов" два. "На остриё" - винительный, "На острие" - предложный. Дальше уже сил нет объяснять.

Comment: Господи! Вам уже не к чему придраться! Неужели обязательно ставить точки? Иначе никто здесь не поймет!